# Need to save a new file with QFileDialog

Tags: c++, qt

I am attempting to give the user an option of saving a file using QFileDialog
However if the file does not exist the File Dialog states that the file does not exist.
I want the QfileDialog to simply tell me the name of the file the user typed so that I can create it. I am doing the following

```
QFileDialog::getOpenFileNames(this, tr("Save File"))
```

and then create a file using the returned string.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [QFileDialog::getSaveFileName](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/qfiledialog.html#getSaveFileName) instead `getOpenFileNames`:

```
 QString fileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, tr("Save File"),
                            "/home/jana/untitled.png",
                            tr("Images (*.png *.xpm *.jpg)"));
```